# Luggage limit when travelling between Krakow and Warsaw by train

Tags: trains, luggage, poland

I am a student studying in Kraków for long time. My studies have now finished and I will be returning to my country.

I have 4 big pieces of luggage (80 cm longest dimension). Is it permitted to use the train from Kraków to Poland capital (Warsaw) with my luggage
or is there a limitation to the number of bags?

Comment: A practical tip, how do you transport 4 suitcase into and out of the trains? Most station and trains will not have people to help you.

Comment: @Willeke he didn't say it were suitcases. With suitcases, it would be impossible, but you certainly can take 4 bags with long stripes.

Comment: actually, it is out of my hand as i have to transfer ny staff as i will not return again, As i have finished my study here

Answer (score 8):

There doesn't seem to be a specific luggage limit, however you may have to pay extra for items that exceed your "standard" storage allotment which is overhead and below your seat. The fee itself seems not a problem (less than 1.50 Euro per piece) but it's unclear how this is managed and where the extra items will go.

I'm guessing a lot of it will depend on the specific layout of the train, how full it is and the attitude of the conductors. Some (but not all) cars have dedicated luggage racks.

I travelled last week in Germany and the Czech Republic in two full trains and it was a disaster: no space for any suitcase, no spaces for a bay carriage and the conductors basically staying out of sight so that the passengers need to battle it our on their own.

Sources:

https://www.polishtrains.eu/support/what-is-the-baggage-allowance-on-polish-trains&id=78

https://www.intercity.pl/en/site/for-passengers/offers/special-offers-for-domestic-transport/przewoz-rzeczy-en/

Comment: In PKP it can get much worse. It is possible that you buy seat X in carriage Y, but there would be no seat X. Or even no carriage Y. In such situations, prepare to argue with the conductors and other passengers.